# SQL-Server: Send email from Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I want to send email using stored procedures

```
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @tableCSS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @tableHTML =
        N'<H3>RewardProgram</H3>' +
        N'<table id="box-table">' +
        N'<tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>' +   
        CAST((SELECT td = WebForm.id, '',
                     td = WebForm.Name, '',
                     td = WebForm.Email, ''
                FROM RewardProgram.dbo.WebForm    
                FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +    
        N'</table>' +
        N'<br/>'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail    
        @profile_name = 'Database Mail Profile',
        @recipients = 'test@mail.com',
        @subject = 'RewardProgram',
        @body = @tableHTML,
        @body_format = 'HTML'    
END
```

When I execute, the **Command(s) completed successfully** but no mail was received

How do I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Database Mail has been set up and tested before I move the code into Stored Procedures

Comment: Is Database Mail enabled ? Did you read all this page (including remarks, permissions, examples)  : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: When you edit the email profile in SSMS, I think there is a 'Test' button. Did you try it ?

Comment: Check your logs for error presence. check this tutorial:
http://ms-sql-queries.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-send-email-from-sql-server.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to send email after creating the `LOGIN` and `USER` for my database with the following:

```
CREATE LOGIN [SystemMail]
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Password';
GO

CREATE USER [SystemMail] FOR LOGIN [SystemMail];
GO

USE RewardProgram
GO

CREATE USER [SystemMail] FROM LOGIN [SystemMail];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'SystemMail';
GO
```